# The original function of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series, analytic-number-theory

I got the following series in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$(which converges uniformly in any compact subset), and I am not sure whether there is a closed form for it. Let $d(k)$ be the number-of-divisors function, eg. $d(p)=1$ for any prime and $d(10)=|\{1,2,5,10\}|=4$. $$f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{d(k)}{k}z^k.$$

By "closed form" I can accept even known special functions.

Comment: Note $d(p)$ is $2$, not $1$. As for your question, I doubt there is a closed form: the series probably just "is what it is".  Arithmetic functions like $d(k)$, which are multiplicative, can lead to nice formulas when used as coefficients of a Dirichlet series, but it'd be pretty weird for anything nice to happen for power series based on the comparison between how you combine terms when multiplying two power series and when multiplying two Dirichlet series. Long ago, people used Lambert series $\sum a_n x^n/(1-x^n)$ for multiplicative $a_n$. And see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204095.

Comment: The best I can say is:$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty d(k)z^{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{z^{k-1}}{1-z^k}$$hence$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{d(k)}kz^k=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\operatorname{Log}(1-z^k)}k.$$